# how to stop taking user inputs and print out arraylist

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, user-input

I am trying to create a program that takes user inputs stores them into an Arraylist and the prints the Arraylist out after user inputs a certain string. my current problem is that i cant get the user inputs to stop and print out. i think what i have currently have is a strong base, i cant see what is wrong.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GroceryArraylist {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        ArrayList<String> Grocerylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an item, enter end to stop ");
        while (!input.equals("end")) {
            Grocerylist.add(input.next());
            if (Grocerylist.equals("end")){
                for(String str:Grocerylist)
                    System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake:

> Grocerylist.equals("end")

GroceryList is of type `ArrayList` and it will never be equal to the string `"end"`. It's like comparing apples with oranges.

You could try this instead:

```
while (!input.equals("end")) {

        String input = input.next();
        Grocerylist.add(input);


        if ("end".equals(input)){
            for(String str:Grocerylist)
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hasNext command to avoid including "end" into the array.

```
public class GroceryArraylist {
  public static void main(String[] args) {        
    ArrayList<String> Grocerylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter an item, enter \"end\" to stop ");
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        Grocerylist.add(input.next());
        if(input.hasNext("end")) {
            System.out.println(Grocerylist);
        break;
        }           
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a do-while loop instead of:

```
public class GroceryArraylist{
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    ArrayList<String> Grocerylist = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an item, enter \"end\" to stop ");

    do {Grocerylist.add(input.next());}
    while (!input.hasNext("end"));
    System.out.println(Grocerylist);
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```